# How to display the Contacts name using Digits-FindFriends?

Tags: android, contacts, twitter-digits, fabric-digits

I am using Digits by Twitter for mobile number authentication by sending OTPs. I need to display a list of user's contacts who have registered for my app like they do in WhatsApp by their contact names. Till now after following the docs of Digits and making use of Find your friends, I am able to show the list of matched contacts. But the list shows user-id, how can I make it to show contact names?. I tried the below code

```
Digits.findFriends(new ContactsCallback<Contacts>() {

        @Override
        public void success(Result<Contacts> result) {
            if (result.data.users != null) {
                // Process data
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Authentication users"
                        + result.data.users.id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            // Show error
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Authentication users"
                    + exception, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you please share the code you have written? As I have integrated digits and find friends and their documentation is really developer friendly!
https://docs.fabric.io/android/digits/find-friends.html

Comment: @Zohair I shared the code.